# Thunderbird: create smart folder

Tags: macos, thunderbird

Several months ago I created a smart folder in Thunderbird, one that works as a saved search action. I want to create another one, but don't remember how to do that, and can't find a decent tutorial.

**How can I create a smart folder in Thunderbird, based on a search action?**

Comment: At the bottom of the search dialogue, there is a button to save as a search folder (if you have limited screen height this may be off-screen). I also forgot for a while, too!

Comment: I see my problem! I always used the search field in the normal window, not the search function (Edit > Find > Search Messages or Shift-CMD-F). If you want the points, make it an answer!

Comment: I've not configured the search box, so I didn't think of that method of searching. Using Linux and Windows and with the folder pane enabled, I normally do my searches by right-clicking on the folder I want to search and selecting **Search Messages...**. There used not to be a right button on a Mac mouse: do you use CMD+click, or is there a right button now? I'd like to include this in my answer for completeness.

Comment: That's the same, just another short cut. (Right clicking is not the problem. On the Mac you can right click if you have a mouse with two buttons. With the touchpad you click with two fingers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bring up a search dialogue box, there is a button <kbd>Save as Search Folder</kbd> at the bottom. Note that this may be off-screen if your screen height is restricted. The subsequent dialogue allows you to name and locate the search folder you create.

With the folder pane enabled, you can bring up the search box by right-clicking on the folder you want to search, and then selecting **Search Messages...**; alternatively, you can use the menu **Edit** -> **Find** -> **Search Messages...**, or use the keyboard short-cut <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on Linux and Windows) - the search folder defaults to the current, but you can change it in the dialogue box.